# PayPal pay now button to confirm payment

Tags: paypal

I have an application that I need to add a paypal pay now button to and I need, once the user has paid, paypal to return back to my site with some sort of confirmation code so that I can add the user's details to the database. There is a redirect url on the setup page but I need to be able to to dynamically set this.

Answer (score 0):

Its true that you can put only one return url in your PayPal account but if you want the return url to be set dynamically then you need to pass the return url from your button code .

For PayPal buttons you need to pass the variable "return=http://yoururl.com" in your button code . In this way it will override the return url you have specified in your PayPal account .

You can check all the button variables [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) .